# Google Spreadsheet COUNTIF formula equivalent with two criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Docs spreadsheet with a few columns. In column D I have values Man OR Woman. In column G I have values Yes OR No. What I would like to to do is to count how many times MAN will answer with YES. So there are two criterias 1.Man and 2.Yes

I have this formula which only counts values in cells D2 and G2. I would like to count values from D2 to D500 and from G2 to G500.

=IF(AND('Revision: 2'!D2="Man",'Revision: 2'!G2="Yes"),1,0)

How I can do that?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a particular case of [Google Docs spreadsheet formula match multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254637/google-docs-spreadsheet-formula-match-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google spreadsheet does not support COUNTIFS function ... however following is one of several formulas you can use for what you want to do ...

```
=ArrayFormula( SUM( ( D2:D500 = "Man" ) * ( G2:G500 = "Yes" ) ) )
```

Comment: This is so dang clever. Multiplication threw me at first, but makes sense upon inspection. +1

Comment: How can we do this with wildcards in string comparison? I couldn't get  =ArrayFormula( SUM( ( Sheet1!M:M = "1. valg*" ) ) ) to work

Answer (score 8):

In the [new version](http://googleblog.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/new-google-sheets-faster-more-powerful.html) of Google Spreadsheets [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) is already built in. You can use it for multiple criteria.

**Sample Usage:**

```
COUNTIFS(A1:A10, ">20", B1:B10, "<30")
COUNTIFS(A7:A24, ">6", B7:B24, "<"&DATE(1969,7,20))
COUNTIFS(B8:B27, ">" & B12, C8:C27, "<" & C13, D8:D27, “<>10”)
```