# Google Sheets formula match multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet like the one shown in the image. What I would like to do is generate a formula that will count how many times *MALEs* from *NEW YORK* choose the *BLUE* color. In column D, the user can enter 1-3 different colors. Column B will be ignored in this case. Can anyone help me with the formula?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula in Google docs

`=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(if(A2:A4="Male",if(C2:C4="New York",If(isnumber(search("Blue",D2:D4)),1)))))`

you can expand it to as many rows as you need