# Count If One Name is in Another Column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count how many times a name shows up in a dynamic column (B:B) that is found in a static column that contains wild cards (A:A). The dynamic column could have 0 names or it could have many names, and a name could show up multiple times.

```
EXAMPLE ONE

Static Column (A:A)     Dynamic Column (B:B)        Count (Output)
-------------------     --------------------        --------------
John*                   Fred Smith                  2
Joe*                    Joe MacDonald
Jane Fairfield          Jane Smith
                        Sally Small
                        John MacDonald
                        ...
```

-

```
EXAMPLE TWO

Static Column (A:A)     Dynamic Column (B:B)        Count
-------------------     --------------------        -----
John*                   Harry Potter                1
Joe*                    Ron Weasley
Jane Fairfield          Jane Fairfield
```

-

```
EXAMPLE THREE

Static Column (A:A)     Dynamic Column (B:B)        Count
-------------------     --------------------        -----
John*                   Hermione Granger            0
Joe*                    
Jane Fairfield
```

-

```
EXAMPLE FOUR

Static Column (A:A)     Dynamic Column (B:B)        Count
-------------------     --------------------        -----
John*                                               0
Joe*                    
Jane Fairfield
```

-

```
EXAMPLE FIVE

Static Column (A:A)     Dynamic Column (B:B)        Count
-------------------     --------------------        -----
John*                   Hermione Granger            3
Joe*                    Ron Weasley 
Jane Fairfield          John MacDonald
                        Joe Sheldon
                        John MacDonald
                        Harry Potter
                        ...
```

I'm running and old Google Spreadsheet, so I cannot use the **countifs** function.

Any insight would be greately appreicated.

Comment: This old topic shows you how you can do this with arrayformula http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338767/google-spreadsheet-countif-formula-equivalent-with-two-criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the `COUNTIF` function applied over an array should do the trick:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(B:B,A:A)))`